# Weekend date sequentially numbered from 1 to n

Tags: python, datetime, sequence

I need your help to sequentially number my weekend days from 1 to n.
Here's my code:

```
start_date = datetime.strptime(getStart_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = datetime.strptime(getEnd_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

weekend_date = []
WE_numberedDays = []

for i in range(delta + 1):
    day = start_date + timedelta(days=i)
    if day.weekday() >= 5:
        weekend_date.append(day)
        
for items in weekend_date:
    WE_numberedDays.append(itmes + 1)
 
print(WE_numberedDays)
```

It print me out [2-2-2-2-2-2-2-] instead I would like [1-2-3-4-6-7-8]. Thank you for your help, hope your having a beautiful day in this rough time.

Comment: What are the values of ```getStart_date``` and ```getEnd_date```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use range

```
WE_numberedDays = list(range(1,len(weekend_date))
```

And now you have the array from 1 to n